# Is Kaer Morhen the place where witchers originated?

Tags: the-witcher

From a [discussion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146066/why-arent-witchers-hunting-during-winter-too/146073?noredirect=1#comment373453_146073) we had with AcePL, it seems there is a possibility that witchers in fact originated in Kaer Morhen, i.e. Alzur and his mentor must have created them there or at least performed the first transmutation there.

I am looking for proof that this claim is true, or something that proves it isn't true.

Games aren't canon in this case.

Just in case it's not clear, I have read all the books (including standalone short stories, *The road with no return* and *Something ends, something begins*), some of them several times; I have also finished all three games (finished the first one 3 times), and read most of the comics (I wish I hadn't).

Some points I would like the answers to address:

- There is the fact that Leo Bonart wears 3 witcher medallions (that I can remember): a wolf, a cat, and some other one (bear of gryphon?).
- Coen is from a different school. How do I know this? Well, Geralt only meets him the winter he brings Ciri in; one would expect Geralt, being second oldest witcher in Kaer Morhen (younger that Vesemir and on par with Eskel) to know everyone who "graduated" after him, especially since there weren't that many graduations.
- I *Season of Storms* we learn that Alzur and his mentor created witchers. Does the book also state that they did this in Kaer Morhen? This seems to be the central question.

Comment: Well, you mean the first witchers? Not necessarily, but I guess we don't know exactly, Season didn't state that AFAIK.

Comment: @Mithoron  -  my thoughts exactly.

Comment: Hmm, it seems Alzur died in Maribor, because of experiment, but also travelled... and both he and his master took hand in creating of witchers. There was also this semi-joke that Vesemir may be older than castle... but there's probably no proof.

Comment: I don't know about the traveling part, but the rest I agree with. I'm very curious as to what AcePL will present as evidence. Or I should just read the books again.

Comment: I just love witcher questions! Although that might not be the case, remember that there are multiple schools (Cat, Viper, Wolf, etc) and they all have different training and specialties. There could've been a group of witchers and they split and founded their schools.

Comment: @BalinsonofFundin  -  my thoughts as well. Alzur couldn't have done the first experiments all by himself. The other renegade mages who helped him could have traveled and performed experiments elsewhere. Thing is, there is really no explicit mention of other schools, or the first school, for that matter.

Comment: is there not a witcher from a different school that is seen in witcher 1? it has been soo long I played it but I seem to remember a guy that was not from Kaer Morhen.

Comment: @Cherubel really? I don't remember one. In any case, we have established that there __are__ different schools; the question is, is Kaer Morhen the first and the original one? That's what AcePL is claiming. Besides, I don't count games as canon for the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 8):

Called to task.

1. ***The Last Wish***:

> Kaer Morhen...  There were produced ones like me. It's not being
>   done anymore.

2. ***Blood of Elves***:

> *Verily, there is nothing so hideous as the monsters, so contrary to nature, known as witchers for they are the offspring of foul sorcery
>   and devilry. They are rogues without virtue, conscience or scruple,
>   true diabolic creations, fit only for killing. There is no place
>   amidst honest men for such as they. And Kaer Morhen, where these
>   infamous beings nestle, where they perform their foul practices, must
>   be wiped from the surface of this earth, and all trace of it strewn
>   with salt and saltpetre.* - Monstrum, or Description of the Witcher

3. ***Blood of Elves***:

> The gelding snorted and jerked its head, crossing what remained of the
>   bridge over the moat. Triss tugged at the reins. The decaying skulls
>   and skeletons strewn across the river bed made no impression on her.
>   She had seen them before.
>
> “I don’t like this,” the girl suddenly remarked. “It’s not as it
>   should be. The dead should to be buried in the ground. Under a barrow.
>   Shouldn’t they?”
>
> “They should,” the magician agreed calmly. “I think so, too. But the
>   witchers treat this graveyard as a… reminder.”
>
> “Reminder of what?”
>
> “Kaer Morhen,” Triss said as she guided the horse towards the
>   shattered arcades, “was assaulted. There was a bloody battle here in
>   which almost all the witchers died. Only those who weren’t in the keep
>   at the time survived.”
>
> “Who attacked them? And why?”
>
> “I don’t know,” she lied. “It was a terribly long time ago, Ciri. Ask
>   the witchers about it.”
>
> “I have,” grunted the girl. “But they didn’t want to tell me.”
>
> I can understand that, thought the magician. A child trained to be a
>   witcher, a girl, at that, who has not undergone the mutations, should
>   not be told such things. A child like that should not hear about the
>   massacre. A child like that should not be terrified by the prospect
>   that they too may one day hear words describing it like those which
>   were screamed by the fanatics who marched on Kaer Morhen long ago.
>   Mutant. Monster. Freak. Damned by the gods, a creature contrary to
>   nature. No, I do not blame the witchers for not telling you about it,
>   little Ciri. And I shan’t tell you either. I have even more reason to
>   be silent. Because I am a wizard, and without the aid of wizards those
>   fanatics would never have conquered the castle. And that hideous
>   lampoon, that widely distributed Monstrum which stirred the fanatics
>   up and drove them to such wickedness was also, apparently, some
>   wizard’s anonymous work. But I, little Ciri, do not recognise
>   collective responsibility, I do not feel the need to expiate the
>   events which took place half a century before my birth. And the
>   skeletons which are meant to serve as an eternal reminder will
>   ultimately rot away completely, disintegrate into dust and be
>   forgotten, will disappear with the wind which constantly whips the
>   mountainside…

4. ***Season of Storms***

> "Winter will come," said with the effort Brehen. "And I, unlike some, have no place to wait it over. Cozy and warm Kaer Morhen not for me."

EDIT:

The conclusion of all those excerpts is that nowhere - up until *Season of Storm* - it's mentioned that there are multiple Schools. We have only faintest hints in form of witchers' medallions in different shapes, but that's that. Also, every time when Kaer Morhen is mentioned, every person knows it was **the** home and source of witchers, including magi who knows best (again, as mentioned in *Season of Storms*), as opposed to **a** home.
In short: multiple Schools as we know them are the game concept only - books mentions only one, in connection with just one other witcher, and there's actually not much more than that. In contrast, the information on the uniqueness of Kaer Morhen is as follows:

1. *Monstrum* says that in order to get rid of witchers Kaer Morhen must
   be destroyed
2. The battle that ensued after wide distribution of the *Monstrum* wiped **nearly all** witchers. It would not be possible if there were more Kaer Morhens elsewhere
3. Even when we get to part where other <s>Schools</s> witchers are mentioned Kaer Morhen is the only place of relative safety for witchers. What's more - those witchers, calling themselves Cats, are known to be failed mutations, defective both from the point of the Trials and in the meaning of true witcher (defender of humanity against the monsters)
4. Indirect mentions of the Keep also are in the context of it being the only source
5. From the bit where Triss contemplates the witchers training and diet of Ciri one can also infer (but this is by no means anything more) that Kaer Morhen area is the place of prevalence of organisms not seen elsewhere, and which are crucial in the forming of the witcher.

EDIT 2:

And I have to retract the statement made elsewhere that *Season of Storms* says that Kaer Morhen is the source. Book states *who* made witchers, not *where*. Damn and blast the *fragilis* of my *memoriam*... So I'm clearing that up.

Comment: The first one is obvious, but the other two are ripped out of context. I would appreciate if you added surrounding paragraph too. Should you stop? No. What you're saying is equivalent to "All the Jews were killed in Auschwitz" meaning "all the Jews in the world were killed in Auschwitz". Or you could imply that there existed no schools of magic except Hogwarts, until the 4th book. To get something straight - I acknowledge that there is no explicit mention of other schools. I simply don't agree that there weren't any.

Comment: Your last comment also mentioned something from *Season of Storms* - you could include that too.

Comment: So what is your resumé from those quotes? What is the actual answer? Is there any summary you can provide based on this? All those quotes just seem to reinforce Kaer Morhen as the *residence* of the witchers, not necessarily their *origin*. The only quote that *might* be interpreted in this regard would be the first one. So yes, you can stop now, but no, it doesn't seem to suffice.

Comment: @CahirMawrDyffrynæpCeallach - Oh really? I would say exactly the opposite: first one is the weakest, because it's context include "School of the Wolf", so Geralt might just state that there are no more Wolves...
I'd say second is almost definitive: "that widely distributed Monstrum" refers to Kaer Morhen **only**. Similarly last quote. Also: saga never even once mentions other witcher sources and just until *SoS* there was not even a word of other Schools (except for extremely weak implication to thereto with two medallions).

Comment: Well, that's all stuff you coudl actually add into the answer to make people see what your conclusion from this wall of quotes is.

Comment: @AcePL  -  in the discussion we had you said that *SoS* explicitly states that Kaer Morhen is the origin. I opened this question to see your proof of this. If you're trying to prove that there is no mention of other school except very weak hints - yes, I agree completely.

Comment: Monstrum was made specifically to target Kaer Morhen - thus it is only natural that it mentions the Keep and the Keep only. 1. and 3. imply nothing at all. And Brehen mentions Kaer Morhen because he knows that Geralt is from the Wolf School and the Wolves stay in Kaer Morhen. Sorry, I'm still not convinced. +1 for the research though.

Comment: It is somewhere suggested that the purpose of Monstrum was not to **wipe down all witchers** but get their secrets - (even Triss is tempted to steal them!) . And just to get the secrets you don't have to kill them all, you just need to conquer ONE place where their secrets are hidden.

Comment: @Yasskier - You're entirely correct. However, In the same chapter that Triss is tempted in, the wording is unequivocal: nearly all the witchers died. There is no qualifier like " who defended the Keep" or "who were there at the time". It says all of them died except the ones who were not in the castle. As for need to conquer just one castle to get to the secrets: you might be right, but you're leaping here without anything to back that up.

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, that improves it a lot. +2